# If you have "return" in brackets, will following code outside of the bracket not be executed?

Tags: swift

Here is the code in question.

```
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        self.userSetDisplayName(user!)
```

So if error != nil and it lets error = error, it will print to the console and return, so it will not run userSetDisplayName. Otherwise if error == nil, it doesnt print and it does not return and it will run userSetDisplayName. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, return is an instruction, it has then so an immediate effect: returning (quitting the current function with) a value.

Comment: why don't you try to run that piece of code?

Comment: tbh going through some shit and wasn't thinking, your completely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Any return statement will end the current subprogram.

Also: This is not a bracket: `{`, it's a curly brace, or just braces

Answer (score 1):

The return statement breaks program flow, ending the function.

If your function reaches return, nothing after it is going to be executed. So if your program enters the if, it never going to execute anything after it.